# Calculating the number of injective functions

Tags: functions

Let $[n] = \{1,2,…,n\}$. Suppose the number of injective functions from  $[5]$ to $[n]$ is $120$. What is  $n$?

My logic:
I thought that $n$ was $5!$ because when we map out the functions we get: $\{(5,1) , (5,2) ... (5,n)\}$. All of these are injective since no two distinct elements in the domain have the same image. Why is it not $5!$ in this case?

The other answer options are:

A) $6$

B) $4$

C) $5$

Comment: Perhaps the downvoters and closevoters could suggest how this question can be improved? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 6):

To construct an injective function $[5]\to[n],$ we must pick $5$ distinct elements of $[n]$ to make up the range--there are $\binom{n}{5}$ ways to do so--and then we must assign each one to one of the $5$ elements of the domain--there are $5!$ ways to do so. Hence, the number of injective functions $[5]\to[n]$ is $$\binom{n}{5}\cdot 5!=\frac{n!}{(n-5)!5!}\cdot 5!=\frac{n!}{(n-5)!}=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4).$$

Thus, we need a way to write $120$ as the product of $5$ consecutive integers. Since $120=5!,$ then $n=5.$

Comment: why only 5 distinct elements of n?

Comment: i thought there was only one element in the domain (5) not 5 elements in the domain..

Comment: By definition $[5]=\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$ Thus, given any function with domain $[5],$ the domain of the function has $5$ elements. If we further require that the function be injective, then the range will also have $5$ elements. Since we're talking about functions $[5]\to[n],$ then the range must be a $5$-element subset of $[n].$ Does that make sense?

Comment: yes this makes sense!! i thought that [5] meant that there was only one element so I got confused. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If we have in domain $|X|=n$ elements and in co-domain $|Y|=m$ then number or all possible functions is $m^n$.

If we restrict ourselves to injective functions then it will be $$[m]_n = m(m-1) \cdots (m-n+1)$$
functions. Proof:

We need to create $n$-length sequence from $Y$ where all elements are different. On first place we have $m$ candidates. Then, for second place we have $m-1$ candidates, so $m(m-1)$ possibilities for 1-st 2 places. Following in same way for last place we have $m-(n-1)$ possibilities, which finish proof.

Comment: yes i know that, that's why i wrote  (5,1), (5,2) , (5, n) . That's correct, right?

Comment: If you understand under each pair one separate function, different from others, then, yes. correct.

Comment: hm, I mean under $[5]$ the $\{5\}$. Anyway fixed. thanks.

Comment: thank you so much!